# Load jar dynamically through javassist

Tags: java, javassist

I'm trying to load a jar with javassist to make it available in the application's current classloader, and I'm getting a `CannotCompileException` due to a `NoClassDefFoundError`

What I got so far is as below:

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
pool.insertClassPath(jarFile);

List<String> classes = listJarClasses(jarFile);
for (final String className : classes) {
    CtClass ctClass = pool.get(className);
    ctClass.toClass(getClass().getClassLoader(), getClass().getProtectionDomain());
}
```

The `listJarClasses` method will just iterate the jar's entries and return the found class names.

I understand this method will indeed load classes to the current classloader, but so far I can't guarantee they will be created in a proper order.

For example, I'm iterating the classes and I got `ClassA` to be added, but this class needs `ClassB` to be compiled and `ClassB` is yet to be added to the classloader by the loop, thus the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

I also understand that there is a way to load classes through `URLClassLoader` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime), but this will not solve the problem, since the class will not be available on the current classloader for future use.

Is there a way to make it simpler to add a jar to the classloader and avoid this?